# Determine if point is in a rectangle using map coordiates

Tags: c#, geography

My brain just isn't working today.  I need to test whether a point (lat, long) lies within a a rectangle on a map.  The rectangle is defined by it's North, East, South, & West borders.  The hiccup is that all points or values are in map-coordinate system.  To deal with the date-line wrap-around, I assume that longitude is always "between" if we go from left-to-right.

```
bool PointInRectangle(Point pt, double North, double East, double South, double West)
{
    // ????
}
```

Comment: Duplicate, I think. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632457/

Comment: @Jeppe Similar-looking problem, but their requirements are a bit different (visual map, doesn't need to be 100% accurate).  I was hoping for a small code snippit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming east and north are positive:

```
bool PointInRectangle(Point pt, double North, double East, double South, double West)
{
    // you may want to check that the point is a valid coordinate
    if (West < East)
    {
        return pt.X < East && pt.X > West && pt.Y < North && pt.Y > South;
    }

    // it crosses the date line
    return (pt.X < East || pt.X > West) && pt.Y < North && pt.Y > South;        
}
```

Comment: Ah - that simple OR is what I was missing.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, I don't think your date-line condition works. Assume `West` is 170 and `East` is -170, then the only valid longitudes are 170 to 180 and -180 to -170. However, the longitude 165 passes the `pt.X > East` condition. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Thanks - I knew it was some simple type of answer!  I'd spent 30 minutes working with 180, 360 and modulo logic and knew there had to be a better way.